# How to turn off Sentry in development and test environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sentry

I set up Sentry for a rails app, but it also logs errors on localhost, which is undesirable.

How can I configure Sentry to only log the `production` and `staging` environments? (not `development` nor `test` environments)

I looked at the [ruby sentry docs](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/ruby/configuration/options/), and the [heroku sentry addon docs](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/sentry) but couldn't see how to do this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
# config/initializers/sentry.rb

...
config.enabled_environments = %w[production staging]
...
```